# Django cors not enable?

Tags: django, reactjs, axios, cors

Hi currently i'm trying to enable cors so i can allow my project frontend side(from another domain) to call my API(using django)
The frontend side using `ReactJS` and `axios` to call the API(i have no knowledge about those forgive me if i got anything wrong) i also have little knowledge about CORS, i only know that it allow cross site domain resource sharing(like api)

I'm using [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers) package in my django i had set `installed_app` and `middleware` the same as the guide. After that i set whitelist for my frontend(they using `ReactJS` localhost to call the api):

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    "http://localhost:3000"
]
```

After that i restart my django server, the frontend calling my API and got the following error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at ‘my api url’ from origin
> ‘http://localhost:3000’ has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn’t pass access control check: The value of the
> ‘Access-Control-Allow-Credentials’ header in the response is ‘’ which
> must be ‘true’ when the request’s credentials mode is ‘include’. The
> credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is
> controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

I even set `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL=True` in the django settings but still got this error

I haven't figure out what i'm missing after reading over django-cors-headers package and this [article](https://www.techiediaries.com/django-cors/) on how to use it

It's my backend problem or the front-end problem ? hope someone can help me

**EDIT:**
Here is what i set my middleware to:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

I notice in my response header when i call by postman don't have `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` or `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: domain name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the frontend side have bad config related to domain name so the settings was fine all along on the backend :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the middleware set in your settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 ]
```

And

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
]
```

Also, try setting your CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL to True for now and see if that works.

Comment: i did all of that and also set `CorsMiddleware` before `CommonMiddleware` like in the document, still got the error

Answer (score 0):

please make sure that this thing is present in your configuration

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    "http://localhost:3000"
]

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000"
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True



CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
    'DELETE',
    'GET',
    'OPTIONS',
    'PATCH',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
)

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',
)
```

Comment: still the same error :(